# Calling WCF on local machine: "Request for principal permission failed"

Tags: wcf

My method is decorated as such:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "OurSecurityGroup")]
```

I'm calling the WCF service from an executable, which I'm just running from Visual Studio while debugging.  If I call the service installed on a server, it works fine, as I've added myself to "OurSecurityGroup" on the server.

If I run the WCF service from my local machine, the service throws a security exception, "Request for principal permission failed".  I've set up the same group on my local machine, and added myself, the local IUSR, all authenticated users and Anonymous Logon.  I know from the FirstPermissionThatFailed property that it is checking for the expected role, OurSecurityGroup.  Who else do I need to add to this group to make this work for local debugging?

Comment: Have you logged off an on again so your account picks up the group membership?

Comment: [Head smack!]  Of course that was it!  Many thanks/